# App Service VNET integration for outbound traffic: can it reach Internet endpoints?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, vnet

I deploy my web application to an `App Service` instance on `Premium` tier. My web application makes outbound requests to external resources on the Internet.

In order to secure the connection with one of these external resources so I can reach it with a private IP address, my plan is to create a `Site-to-Site VPN` from `Azure` to `Oracle Cloud Infrastructure` (where the external resource resides). Then, I plan to use the `VNET Integration` for outbound traffic and connect my `App Service` to my `VPN`.

My question is - will the web application still be able to reach the other external resources on the Internet with their public IPs? I believe the answer is related to routing tables but I can't wrap my mind around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you integrate a Regional VNet (I'm assuming) doesn't mean the app service won't be able to make outbound connections. Pretty much like

[image]

When you integrate your app service with your VNet that has the site-to-site VPN, traffic from your app service will [traverse the Azure network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security#resources-inside-an-azure-virtual-network) rather than going out to internet, assuming your app service is using an RFC1918 address for your infrastructure. If you want to secure the traffic even further, then your app service would need to be hosted inside an [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/overview)